Should we keep the "reverse-engineering" tag?
Right now we have a reverse-engineering tag. I would like to raise the question of whether we should keep it or not, and suggest we remove it.
If my answer gains enough upvotes and not too many downvotes/objections, I plan on removing the tag from all related questions and thus delete it. Other users are encouraged to argue against removing the tag or perhaps offer alternatives in additional answers.  

Right now the reverse-engineering tag has a dozen questions, four of which by a single user, who's also relatively new to stack-exchange. Eleven out of the twelve questions were asked by a user of under 200 reputation points in RE.SE and only two other questions were opened by a single user with a reputation slightly above 100.
This tag seems somewhat redundant, as the entire site is about reverse-engineering and I can think of only a handful of questions that won't fit under it.
This tag also has neither usage guidance nor wiki content, and I find it hard to say those questions share any common ground (except, obviously, generally being about reverse engineering)
Edit:
So there's a single closed question I couldn't remove the reverse-engineering tag of (because that would lead to 0 tags) and there's no appropriate tag for it. I flagged it for deletion, hoping that'd let us get rid of the tag. I also edited the tag's wiki to point out it is redundant.
